# Receive result from DialogFragment after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Implementing intercommunication between a `Fragment` and a `DialogFragment`. (without involving `Activity` and `ViewModel`)

It's working fine until orientation changes in `DialogFragment`, and I believe as a result of destruction and recreation, the `DialogFragment` loses the reference to the fragment's listener. Any solution?

**Fragment** (Caller)

```
private fun getRoles() { 
    val dialog = RoleDialog() // DialogFragment
    setFragmentResultListener("roles", this::onFragmentResult)
    dialog.show(parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), "roleDialog")
}

private fun onFragmentResult(requestKey: String, bundle: Bundle) {
    roles = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("roles", Role::class.java)
}
```

**DialogFragment** (RoleDialog)

Within the `DialogFragment`, I have an `OK` button to dismiss the dialog and set the result back to the caller Fragment.

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener {
    dialog?.dismiss()
    setFragmentResult("roles", bundleOf("roles" to roles))
}
```

**Problem:** `onFragmentResult` in the calling Fragment doesn't get called after the orientation changes in `DialogFragment`

**Reference:** https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-between-fragments

Comment: The docs specifically show `setFragmentResultListener` called in a lifecycle method, ensuring that it is always called even after a config change. Is there a reason you aren't following the guide you linked?

Comment: Is there a way to keep the loop `(Fragment->DialogFragment->Fragment)` intact via `FragmentManager`? Other methods are last resort and I'll accept the answer if that's the case. Referenced link doesn't use lifecycle for communication between fragments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Every call to `setFragmentResultListener` takes a `LifecycleOwner` (the Kotlin extension just does this automatically for you), so they all use lifecycle.

Comment: because I'm relatively new to this and that's why I'm not sure about a solution, is it possible for you to guide me in a direction using code based on above?

Comment: moving `setFragmentResultListener(...` within `onCreateView` solved the problem, It was the repeating assignment in `getRoles` that was causing the issue.